# How Bitcoin/Ethereum or other cryptocurrency node knows about IP of peers at start

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

Recently, I have worked on my own blockchain based cryptocurrency and I have an architecture question. How new node in network knows to which peer to connect?

I had an idea that IPs can be specified in config file were user specifies nodes he/she wants. But I want to automate this process. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hardcoded list / a file of IP addresses called bootstrap nodes.

A fresh peer-to-peer client will try to connect to these first.

If the client does not manage to connect it will never find the network.

Comment: Is there another way to find other nodes in network?

Comment: You can scan all the IP address in the world starting from 1.1.1.1

Comment: I thought I can you some kind of broadcasting of my own address and then other nodes will add themselves to my peer list

Comment: It only works if your nodes are in the same network. Blockchains are rarely needed for local area networks.

Comment: Or to put it other way around... there is no "broadcast" that works in Internet.